# Filling a list of comboboxes

Tags: model, qml

Updating an already existing application, I try to add a combobox to each line of an automatically generated dialog.
The dialog would receive its data from outside QML and the number of rows can differ.

The code basically looks like

```
{
  contentItem: Column
  Repeater
  {
     model: valueModel
     delegate: Row
     {

       function fillComboBox()
       {
          var choices = ChoiceListElement.choices;
          if(typeof choices !== "undefined")
          {
            for(var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++)
            {
               comboboxModel.append({text: choices[i]});
            }
         }
       }

       Item
       {
              Component.onCompleted:
              {
                 fillComboBox();
              }
       }
       function format()
       {
          var formatted_string = name;
          return formatted_string;
       }
       Text
       {
         text: format()
       }
       ComboBox
       {
         id: combo
         width: 50
         model: comboboxModel
       }
     }
  }
ListModel
{
    id: comboboxModel
}
```

From what I see, there is one combobox per line, as required.
However, all comboboxes seem to share the same content, probably due to the fact that each of them is picking up the same model.

How would I assign one model per line?

desired:

```
content Combobox 1:
 * option A
 * option B

content Combobox 2:
 * option C
 * option D
```

Any ideas on that?

Thanks in advance!

Michael

UPDATE:

- fixed delegate in code above, was already as shown above in original code
- added code to show how combobox model is populated.

Comment: Where does options A,B,C,D come from? Also, aren't the Text and `ComboBox` wrapped in a single delegate `Item` in your actual code?

Comment: thanks for your questions, GrecKo, I've updated the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to move declaration of 'comboboxModel' inside of the delegate to create new model for every combobox.